# How to update from input type date to input type text field dynamically in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, dynamic

I want to create a **input field** with **date** but when user type his **name** for search then it also work in the same field.

More specifically I want make a **dynamic** input field with **text** and **date** input field in a search filter button in **JavaScript**.

Is it possible to create a field with date and later when user want to search by name then he able to search the name in same field and if he wants to search filter by date he also able to search in same field.

If it's possible then how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `setAttribute(attr, value)` property to change the attribute types.
[More can be found here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)

Example using buttons:

```js
function searchByName(){
  document.getElementById("search").setAttribute("type","text");
}

function searchByDate(){
  document.getElementById("search").setAttribute("type","date");
}
```

```html
<button onclick="searchByName();">Search by name</button> 
<button onclick="searchByDate();">Search by date</button>

<input type="date" name="search" id="search" />
```

**EDIT**

If you want to dynamically change based on input, you can try this:

```js
const searchInput = document.getElementById("search");

searchInput.addEventListener("keydown",(e)=>{
    const isNumber = /\d/.test(e.key)
    if(isNumber){
        searchByDate();
    }
    else{
        searchByName()
    }
},{once:true});

function searchByName(){
  document.getElementById("search").setAttribute("type","text");
}

function searchByDate(){
  document.getElementById("search").setAttribute("type","date");
}
```

```html
<input type="date" name="search" id="search" />
```

**PS: The above script will run only once. If your user has pressed the first key a number, then the input will remain as date otherwise, it will change to text**

Comment: Hi @Lokendra can I use only a field and switch that in same field without creating two buttons.